# Setting data element dynamically

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-4

I'm trying set an data element dynamically after a selection is made from a selection menu.
The dynamic selection is working fine however the element is being set as "undefined" in my view.

In my companies controller I'm getting the company prefix by id. This returns the correct prefix by company id.

```
public function getcompanyprefix($id)
{
    $company = Company::find($id);
    return Response::make([$company->prefix]);
}
```

Here in my jquery i'm getting the company prefix and appending it to a  but element.prefix returns undefined.

```
$('.admin-select').change(function() {

        $.getJSON("/companies/getcompanyprefix/"+$(this).val(), function(data) {

        var coprefix = $('#coprefix');
        coprefix.empty();

        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            coprefix.append("<span>" + element.prefix + "</span>");
        });


    });


});
```

Comment: I don't know laravel-4, but looks like you're returning the prefix only, try using element only instead of element.prefix maybe?

Comment: Sometimes its just that easy. Thank you!

Comment: No worries. Just don't ask me how to return an object with properties from laravel-4 :)

Comment: @snorth you should've used`Response::json()`. anyways, glad the issue was solved.